# Не просят пароль, хотя подтвердил почту

Tags: поддержка

Я нажал кнопку "Изменить настройки подписки" и подтвердил введённую почту. Однако нигде на этих этапах меня не просили написать пароль. На почту сгенерированный пароль тоже не пришёл. Если я сейчас выйду с аккаунта, то как мне зайти на него обратно?

UPD:

В итоге нашёл кнопку "Добавить дополнительные способы входа...", где указал ту же почту и новый пароль. Теперь в способах входа у меня 2 строчки с одной почтой. Что означает строчка без пароля и почему так сделано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Адрес почты регистрации и адрес в способе входа other различаются.
2. Судя по всему, вариант без пароля - это вход через внешнюю систему, вероятно - яндекс.

PS: Сорри, если от яндекса пришло письмо о попытке входа, я просто экспериментировал, как он отреагирует на указание такого email'а.

[image]

Comment: В строчке other вижу ту же почту, что я и подтверждал изначально. В строчке Stack Exchange (та что с паролем) не вижу никакого адреса. Так что почта должна совпадать. Могу даже скинуть скрины того, что первое письмо пришло от Stack Overflow с просьбой подтвердить почту просто. А второе письмо уже в рассылках с заголовком "Finish Adding Log In". Да, письмо от яндекса пришло, но я яндексом не пользовался вообще.

Comment: Наверное, у меня бы всё равно получилось зайти, если бы нажал "Забыли пароль?". Тогда бы всё равно на подтверждённую почту уведомление должно прийти о смене пароля (установке нового?) по идее, но зачем изначально такую ситуацию создавать непонятно...

Comment: @dIm0n, ответил в модераторских сообщениях.