# Не удаётся сменить пароль -- ограничения на формат или неверный ввод текущего?

Tags: поддержка, локализация

Пытаюсь изменить пароль для логина в аккаунт ruSO и получаю ошибку (стоит перевести, кстати):

> An error occurred while attempting to reset password.

При этом выше всё это время написано:

> Пароли должны содержать не менее восьми символов, включая как минимум
> 1 букву и 1 цифру.

И текущий пароль, и пароль, на который хочу поменять, удовлетворяют этим требованиям. Через несколько попыток получаю:

> Слишком много неудачных попыток ввода текущего пароля; пожалуйста,
> попробуйте ещё раз позже или посетите страницу восстановления учётной
> записи.

Значит ли это, что срабатывает какое-то другое ограничение? Какой тогда полный список ограничений на формат пароля? Или может это связано с [этим вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10654/398802), и я пытаюсь изменить пароль не там, вводя неправильный текущий пароль (*править -> доступ -> способы входа -> Stack Exchange -> изменить пароль*)?

Если ввести неверный текущий пароль специально, то получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ввести новый пароль без букв (`123456789`) специально, то получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, если бы проблема была в одной из этих причин, она бы вылезла раньше.

Comment: Я давно менял пароли, но у меня вроде приняло, правда у меня пароли были сложные.

Comment: Буквы - латинские?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, [a-z]

Comment: `включая как минимум 1 букву и 1 цифру.` значит, что `[a-z]` как бы не годится...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor это про тип букв было, цифры тоже есть

Comment: Я имею в виду может надо там всякие `[A-Z]`, `!@#$%^&*()_-+=` ;)